# Installing cmark PECL module without root

Tags: php, linux, configure, pecl, php-7.3

I'm trying to install the [cmark PECL module](https://pecl.php.net/package/cmark) on a shared web host. **I do not have sudo privileges.**

I was able to get cmark compiled and installed to my home directory. The libcmark.so file is in /home/XXX/progs/lib. The cmark.h file (and other header files) are in /home/XXX/progs/include.

I was able to run phpize. I'm now trying to run `./configure` with the following command:

`./configure --prefix="/home/XXX/progs" --with-php-config=/usr/local/php73/bin/php-config LDFLAGS="-L/home/XXX/progs/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/XXX/progs/include/"`

I get an error message when I do this.

`checking for libcmark... checking for cmark_markdown_to_html in -lcmark... yes
checking for libcmark headers... checking for cmark files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the cmark distribution`

cmark is compiled properly, and I was able to get the configuration script to find the lib directory just fine, but I can't get the configuration script to find the headers.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out a solution. I edited the configuration script. There's a line which says `SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr"`. I changed the line to read `SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr /home/XXX/progs"`. That change allowed it to complie.